# Will a keep-alive failure on a POSIX TCP socket cause a pending read() to return?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, posix

Given the following sequence of events:

- A `read()` is executed on a POSIX TCP socket that has keep-alive enabled and for which no data is available.
- The keep-alive mechanism decides that the connection is broken.

and assuming that `SIGPIPE` is being ignored, will the `read()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return -1 with `errno == ECONNRESET.`

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @SteveEmmerson There's probably no single reference for that, it's deduced and empirical. Enabling tcp keepalive causes the TCP stack to periodically send out empty segments, if they're not ack'ed, the TCP connection is deemed broken, an RST is sent out, while also  communicated back to the local application much like any other segment that the TCP stack would time out due to missing ACKs.

Comment: @nos Thanks. The reason I'm wary is because I learned the hard way that `close()`ing  a socket in one thread won't cause a `select()` or `poll()` on that socket in another thread to return -- so sockets don't always behave as they "should".

Comment: This isn't a socket API behaviour, it is a TCP behaviour. It's defined in [RFC 1122 #4.2.3.6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1122#section-4.2.3.6). The behaviour when the keep-alive segment transmission times out is defined in RFC 793 of course. The socket API has no option but to deliver the reset to the application. @nos

Comment: Re your close/select poll issue, I don't see why closing a socket should trigger a select event, except maybe an error. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @EJP that's only if it receives the RST from the peer. If the peer is just vanished, you'll get ETIMEDOUT (at least on linux).

Comment: @nos Re: close & poll/select, I expected that the poll/select would return and indicate that a read on the socket wouldn't block -- and that the read would either return 0 bytes or an error condition. Alas, this doesn't occur -- leading to more complex (workaround) code.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson I would expect `select()` to return -1/EBADF myself, or else block until something happened on an open socket, ... So there you go :-|